# More generic action command

Tags: visualforce, outputlink, urlfor

I have an apex:outputLink that redirects to an Account detail page, `selectedId` is the Account Id, eg:

```
<apex:outputLink
    value="{!URLFOR($Action.SObject.View, selectedId)}" //pseudocode example
    rendered="{!IF(selectedId != null, true, false)}"
/>
```

What if I wanted to make this more general so `selectedId` could be an Account Id *or* a Contact Id?

Can I modify this line of code to account for both cases, or will I need two separate outputLinks and render one or the other?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this the naughty way (least code) using just the Id:

```
<apex:outputLink
    value="/{!selectedId}" //pseudocode example
    rendered="{!IF(selectedId != null, true, false)}"
/>
```

or the nice, robust way (bleeds complexity into Apex) by using a controller:

```
<apex:outputLink
    value="{!View}" //pseudocode example
    rendered="{!IF(selectedId != null, true, false)}"
/>

public PageReference getView() {
    return new ApexPages.StandardController(selectedId).view();
}
```

or render a variant for each (more complexity in your Visualforce)

```
<apex:outputLink
    value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, selectedId)}" //account
    rendered="{!BEGINS(selectedId, '001')}"
/>

<apex:outputLink
    value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, selectedId)}" //contact
    rendered="{!BEGINS(selectedId, '003')}"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the various ways to implement it and EXTRA thank you for that nifty BEGINS method. This whole time I was using a massive IF statement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what $Action.SObject.View is but you can likely just use the exact same code for this.

If you can't then doing something like the following will allow you to:

```
<apex:outputLink target="_top" value="{!selectedId}" rendered="{!selectedId != null}">
```

You may need a / in front of the Id.  I can't remember.  I always have to test this part:

```
<apex:outputLink target="_top" value="/{!selectedId}" rendered="{!selectedId != null}">
```